# Property 'getFolderByServerRelativeUrl' does not exist on type 'IWeb'

Tags: sharepoint-online, api, pnpjs

I can not access getFolderByServerRelativeUrl() in pnp API.

`await sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl()`

Error:

> Property 'getFolderByServerRelativeUrl' does not exist on type 'IWeb'.

Comment: Which version of PnP JS you are using?

Comment: Thanks. I am using version 2.0.6. I am able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I just change

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
```

to

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";
```

Then it works.